# Eclipse install new software popup

Tags: eclipse, aspectj

I'm using `eclipse Luna` and when I imported maven (integrated with `AspectJ`) project into it , it show a popup proposing to install `Maven AspectJ plugin`. I clicked cancel accidentally. How can I install what Eclipse propsed me to do now?

Here's an example of the popup I talked about:

[image]

I clicked "Cancel" accidentally, how can I re-show that popup and click "Finish" to install the plugins?

Answer (score 0):

**Open Eclipse - Click Help go to Installation details** and see the software's which are installed. **Click maven - click update button**...

It will install the software for u

If u want a **fresh installation** then open **Eclipse - click Help go to install new software, Click Add**, if u are having the zip file u can upload it by archive or local, if u don't have any zip file, then paste the URL in the location, click ok

It will install the software